# Javascript Value Comparison Explanation

Tags: javascript, comparison, conditional-statements

What is the difference between these two conditional statements in Javascript?

```
function comparisonTest() {
  var value = "A value";
  var compare1 = 5;
  var compare2 = "String";
  var compare3 = false;

  if (value == compare1 || value == compare2 || value == compare3) console.write("True");
  else console.write("False");
}
```

This works as it should - it returns false because the values don't match. However, when I change the conditional to the following...

```
function comparisonTest() {
  var value = "A value";
  var compare1 = 5;
  var compare2 = "String";
  var compare3 = false;

  if (value == compare1 || compare2 || compare3) console.write("True");
  else console.write("False");
}
```

it *always* returns `True`. I thought that maybe there would be a shorter way of writing that condition for multiple comparisons (although a loop would function just fine), but this is clearly not a way to approach this.

What is going on behind-the-scenes or, rather, how is it being interpreted so that in the second case it always returns true? None of the values I declared are `1` or `true`, so that's definitely not the problem.

Comment: That's a logical operator.  You can't do that.

Comment: The question actually abut the || operator, not equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not believe there is a short way to write conditionals in JavaScript.

The reason the second example returns true is because when you evaluate `compare2` this is a `truthy` value in JavaScript.

I recommend this [post](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/)  about truthy and falsey values in JavaScript

As an aside you may want to look into the difference between `==` and `===` in JavaScript

Comment: I'll accept this answer soon - thank you for the reference; I didn't know that there were `truthy` and `falsey` values in Javascript... this is interesting, and I'll keep it in mind when I'm working with Javascript! I take this over the answer from @jfriend00 because you gave me a reference that actually explains what the values are and what they mean.

Answer (score 2):

That's because this:

```
if (value == compare1 || compare2 || compare3)
```

is the same as this:

```
if ((value == compare1) || compare2 || compare3)
```

And, you will see that `compare2`is a truthy value which satisfies the `||` operator.  See [this MDN article on operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for why the `==` gets evaluated first which makes your first code block work, but makes your second one evaluate like I've shown.

---

If you want to compare all of them to `value`, you have to write it out the longhand way like you did in your first code block where you compare each one separately to `value`.

---

You may also want to look into using `===` more often so then you don't have to worry about possible type conversions making things equal that you never intended to be equal.  I have a guideline in my own coding to always used `===` and `!==` unless there's an explicit reason to want a type conversion.  I believe this saves some accidental bugs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the evaluation of the second conditional to how the compiler interprets it - I was wondering how it determined what to evaluate. Also, I appreciate you pointing out the use of `===`, however the type conversion was something that I knew was not an issue in this case. As well, I have already read that SO question, but thank you for linking it nonetheless!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice - you may find this article on operator precedence in javascript useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: The choice of equality operator is irrelevant here.

Comment: @RobG - yes I know that - just a general "good coding" recommendation when they are mixing types.

Comment: Hmmm, "good coding". I've never seen a good argument to **always** use one over the other—if `'5' !== 5` is required, the programmer had better be certain. But that discussion has been held elsewhere. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - My guideline for my own coding is that unless I explicitly want a type conversion, I should ALWAYS use `===` or `!==`.  I didn't say everyone should always do that or that's the only way to do it.  I said that it's a guideline I use and I believe it prevents bugs, thus I recommend it to others.

Comment: I have to agree with both of you. 1. The different types were simply to demonstrate the question - in reality the entire block is full of strings. However, I do always use `===` when I'm checking values I know to be of a certain type (as in my 'real' case, where I'm looking for `if (value === stringX)`. Thank you for the warning though :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
function comparisonTest() {
  var value = "A value";

  var answers = [5, "String", false];

  /* IE may requires shim found here:
     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf
  */
  if (answers.indexOf(value) === -1) {
    // False
  } else {
    // True
  }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! And actually, it's just what I needed. I have a list of about 100 comparison strings that I previously put into an array and looped through (sloppy); this is *much* more elegant, thank you :)

Comment: The usual ES5 caveat should be included, but +1 anyway. :-)

Comment: @RobG -- I assume you are referring to  the shim being needed?  Yea, I meant to include that.

Comment: This is all server-side Google code that doesn't actually run in any browser. It's just used to script Google's services (Calendar, Spreadsheet, etc.) and their back-end is up-to-date :)